# Read from a SQL database and output result to a file

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

Afternoon,

I’m trying to code a form that will run a query on one of my databases and put the result in a text file.

But am not able to accomplish the output of the files. Can someone tell me how I can output the file? I think i am missing a streamwriter but I am not sure how to do it.

Kindly advise.

A

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SwiftMSGDownload
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    string RdSqlMsg;
    string RdSqlRef;
    string RdSqlType;
    string RdSqlTime;
    string MSGRootPath;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void subGetMSGs_Click()
    {                      
        string Sql = null;

        Sql = "SELECT [FileNumber] " + " ,[Reference] " + " ,[SenderRefID] " + " ,[Amount] " + " ,[Currency] " + " ,[Type] " + " ,[DateTransfer] " + " ,[Time] " + " ,[Msg] " + " ,[Direction] " + " ,[ProcessBy] " + " ,[SenderID] " + " ,[ReceiverID] " + " FROM  [TransferFilesIn] " + " WHERE  Time BETWEEN '" + txtLastTimeProcessed.Text + "' AND '" + DateTime.Now + "'" + " AND Type IN (199,103) " + " AND ReceiverID = 'ABCDEFXXX' ";

        try
        {
            string strConnectionString = null;
            strConnectionString = "Data Source=180.123.45.6;Password=thepassword;User ID=theuser;Initial Catalog=thedatabase;Persist Security Info = True";
            txtSwiftDBConnectionString.Text = strConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection connObj = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmdObj = new SqlCommand(Sql, connObj))
                {
                    connObj.Open();

                    using (SqlDataReader readerObj = cmdObj.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        //Loops through all returned records.
                        while (readerObj.Read())
                        {
                            RdSqlMsg = readerObj["Msg"].ToString();
                            RdSqlRef = readerObj["Reference"].ToString();
                            RdSqlType = readerObj["Type"].ToString();
                            RdSqlTime = readerObj["Time"].ToString();

                            RdSqlTime = RdSqlTime.Replace(":", "-");
                            RdSqlTime = RdSqlTime.Replace("/", "-");

                           string strFilePath = MSGRootPath + "\\" + RdSqlTime + "_" + RdSqlRef + "_" + RdSqlType + ".txt";
                        }
                    }

                    //Close the connection
                    connObj.Close();
                  }
              }
         }
         catch (Exception ex) 
         {
            MessageBox.Show("subGetMSGs_Click - ERROR: " + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message);
            return;
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       MSGRootPath = "\\\\180.987.65.43\\Public\\Test";
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        subGetMSGs_Click();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow.  I googled, "c# write to text file", and there is an endless list of examples.

Comment: See this link - [Data to text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174077/export-a-c-sharp-dataset-to-a-text-file). Hope it might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System.Io;

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
{
while (readerObj.Read())
{
string something = "";
sw.writeline(something);
}
}
```

Just make something your formatted output for each item the reader returns.

Answer (score 0):

See:

```
File.WriteAllText
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext(v=vs.110).aspx

and

```
File.AppendAllText
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356(v=vs.110).aspx

Pass your file path and your message strings into one of those methods and it will write a text file.