# How to export data from Access to a text file

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

net. My question is how to export data from Access to a text file using vb.net. In my database has Table1 which consists FirstName and LastName so I want this data to be exported to a text file.

I stumble on this code and run it and when compiled it but nothing is export to the text file. Can Someone help my with this?

```
    Dim connetionString As String
    Dim cnn As OleDbConnection
    connetionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Scripts\db.mdb;"
    cnn = New OleDbConnection(connetionString)

        cnn.Open()
        Dim AccessCommand As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * INTO [Text;HDR=No;DATABASE=C:\Scripts\TextFiles].[Result.txt] FROM Table1", cnn)
        cnn.Close()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can I know why my question is downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is downvoted is because you can actually find plenty of example from the website.

Perhaps you do not know what keyword to search?
Try something like "dataset to textbox"?
or something here? [Export a C# DataSet to a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174077/export-a-c-sharp-dataset-to-a-text-file)
**Updated**
I understand you may be new to vb. I will not give you the exact code but tell you what you can do.

First, declare a dataTable/dataset (I would prefer DataTable) to hold your query result from DB.

```
    Dim dtresult As DataTable = 'Result from DB
```

Then loop through the datatable rows and get the data append into a string builder(or any other way you like to build your string)
Then append the string into the txt file.
This is something you can do.

**UPDATE 2**
Okay, something like this.

```
    Private Sub DataTableToTXT()

    Dim connetionString As String
    Dim cnn As OleDbConnection
    connetionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Scripts\db.mdb;"
    cnn = New OleDbConnection(connetionString)

    Dim dtResult As New DataTable
    cnn.Open()
    'Change the query
    Dim dataAdap As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM TABLE1", cnn)
    dataAdap.Fill(dtResult)
    cnn.Close()

    'Change the path to your desired path
    Dim exportPath As String = "C:\Export\"
    Dim exportFileName As String = "data.txt"

    If Not Directory.Exists(exportPath) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(exportPath)
    End If

    Dim writer As New StreamWriter(exportPath + exportFileName)
    Try
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder

        For Each row As DataRow In dtResult.Rows
            sb = New StringBuilder
            For Each col As DataColumn In dtResult.Columns
                sb.Append(row(col.ColumnName))
            Next
            writer.WriteLine(sb.ToString())
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    Finally
        If Not writer Is Nothing Then writer.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: I wonder where do you learn this line of code from? 
     Dim AccessCommand As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * INTO [Text;HDR=No;DATABASE=C:\Scripts\TextFiles].[Result.txt] FROM Table1", cnn)

Comment: I got it from http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/convert-access-table-text-file-using-vbulletin-t2909383.html

Comment: I think it is not gonna achieve your goal.
what you how to do is first assign your data retrieve form DB into a Dataset/DataTable.
Then use a string builder to loop through the dataset/datable
Build the string and append in into the file.

Comment: Can you explain it to me? sorry I'm still new to vb.net

Comment: So I have to declare for example Dim query = "SELECT * INTO TEXT 'C:\Scripts\Result.txt'"

Comment: This code work perfectly! If you don't mind answering another question, why I can't select certain field name for example SELECT CN,FirstName FROM TABLE1? When I run this query it gives me "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll"

Comment: Is the field name you select exist in the DB?
Put a breakpoint and debug and see whats happening.

Comment: It ok I found the problem. I accidently open the database thus the code cannot run that part. Anyway thank you very much for helping me solving this code.