# VB.net SQL output loop rename file error on next loop

Tags: sql, vb.net, inout

new to the stack here. I am developing some tools for work that allow us to pull information from a database and then operate on it with additional custom code. Since I need the output to not have a header, I want to have one file (as defined by schema.ini) that I will temporarily write the data into then copy and rename it before starting again. Using VS2017, when I debug it spits out the error that it cannot find RawC.txt after the first iteration. I cannot seem to figure out why. It is probably something simple but I have been unable to locate online. Can anyone help me out here? Below is the block I am having trouble with:

`For each of the three files, output the sorted list. Schema has the correct format`

```
 For index = 0 To 2
       If index = 0 Then
          whicharr = arrSt(1)
       ElseIf index = 1 Then
          whicharr = arrSe(1)
       ElseIf index = 2 Then
          whicharr = arrVi(1)
       End If
       stopFile = "SELECT " & complist(index) & " INTO [Text;Database=" & TMPath & "].[RawC.txt] FROM [" & whicharr & "] ORDER BY " & complist(index)
       cmd = New OleDbCommand(stopFile, conn)
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
       'Now Copy and rename this file
       My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(TMPath & "\RawC.txt", TMPath & "\" & whicharr & ".txt")
       'And delete the old RawC.txt file
       My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(TMPath & "\RawC.txt")
 Next
```

The final output from this loop should be three unique files that I will pass to another code that will perform some math on it.

Comment: Is 'stopFile' some sql that you are hoping writes directly to a file? Does this code throw any errors?

Comment: So stopfile is simply the string that holds the SQL command. It pulls information from a table and prints only the part I am interested in to RawC.txt. The error I get is after the first iteration, where it tells me that the object RawC.txt cannot be found.

Comment: Are you using MS-Access? Does the value of stopFile look sensible after you've assigned it?

Comment: Yes, I am using MS-Access, which is a nightmare. The string in stopfile looks sensible. That was my first thought as well that something did not come out correctly in the string. My best guess is something happens during the copy/rename and delete. If I write out three commands as different blocks, it works fine. I was trying to clean that up with a smaller loop.

Comment: Which line throws the error? Does the file exist in the TMPath folder location at that line?

Comment: How about just getting the datatable and interating through to write out your values. Pretty comprehensive answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23905927/how-to-export-data-from-access-to-a-text-file

Comment: The line that throws the error is cmd.executenonquery(). It points out that the object RawC.txt cannot be found. When index = 0, everything runs fine. When it goes to the next loop, the error occurs on the executenonquery.  To answer Andrew Mortimer, it does not make sense for me to iterate through the tables, since I need to pull chunks of data, operate on them, and then do it again N times. It would be way to slow to iterate through the table each time. Printing out the table temporarily is much more efficient the way I have it set up.