# Save datatable value in .txt file c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is the table:
[image]

I want to fetch all the column and row of this table and save in a .txt file.

The text file name must be SubscriberID.txt(example:281063.txt or 281064.txt) and save in a Folder Name manoj.

In 281063.txt file the data save in SubscriberID:60;npercentscore:60;nevaleid:7091,courseID:1,...
LIKE THIS.

```
Here i take all the data to a datatable:
string query = "SELECT * FROM DATAFETCH";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
```

How can i achieve my target using c# asp .net??
any suggestion??

---

You already have half of what you need. i too was looking for a solution to this problem and this seemed to have worked for me.

after you close the connection i would add this

```
Like So
```

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(attachmentLocation + dr["SubscID"].ToString()" + x + ".txt"); //create the file
                        
                        foreach (DataRow dr in ResultsTable.Rows)
                        {
                            
                            string line = "ACCTNUMBER:" +dr["Account"].ToString() +"\n";
                            //and so on
                            sw.WriteLine(line); //write data
                           // x++;
                            
                        }

                        sw.Close();
```

```
And the reason i did this is because when i added the write file within the loop it would create and replace the file everytime.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export a C# DataSet to a text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174077/export-a-c-sharp-dataset-to-a-text-file)

Comment: sir i want to save the file in folder according to the name of SubscriberID.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need one file per row, you can do it like this:

```
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(PathToStoreTheFile + dr["SubscriberID"].ToString() + ".txt"); //create the file
            string line = "SubscriberID:" + dr["SubscriberID"].ToString() + ";";
            line += "npercentscore:" + dr["npercentscore"].ToString() + ";";
            line += "nevaleid:" + dr["nevaleid"].ToString() + ";";
            line += "courseID:" + dr["courseID"].ToString() + ";";
            //and so on
            sw.WriteLine(line); //write data
            sw.Close();
        }
```

Or you can also iterate through the columns:

```
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(PathToStoreTheFile + dr["SubscriberID"].ToString() + ".txt");
            string line = "";

            foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
            {
                line += dc.ColumnName + ":" + dr[dc].ToString() + ";";
            }
            sw.WriteLine(line);
            sw.Close();
        }
```

Comment: yes i want 1 file per row ...and file name must be  SubscriberID.txt..can you suggest me??

Comment: Here you are...

Comment: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\281063.txt' is denied.error in StreamWriter

Comment: For the path C:\Program Files (x86) you need to have administrative permissions. If you have not this error will appear. Please don't place the generated files in this folder...